# Incorrect boundary string in multipart/mixed message

Tags: delphi, indy10

I'm using Delphi 2006 to create and send an email message with an attachment in a personal-use-only application. I send the message with an instance of TIdSMTP, and then also put a copy into a specific IMAP folder with an instance of TIdIMAP4. This all works very nicely with the version of Indy 10 that was distributed with BDS2006, with one exception: the time is always incorrect in the email header.

I decided to fix that if I could, and after searching for a solution it seemed most reasonable to get the latest Indy 10 snapshot and use that.

That puts the correct time into the email header, but there's a new problem. The boundary string is now different in the header of the message that is added to the IMAP folder than what comes in the body of the email! (Please note that the message that was sent via SMTP is correct.)

This is the relevant header information from the older version of Indy 10:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="XNlC6OyS4QSiHY2U=_jsXyps6TR34pFNsh"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2011 09:11:58 +0000

A test of the BDS2006-bundled version of Indy

--XNlC6OyS4QSiHY2U=_jsXyps6TR34pFNsh
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
        name="20111122.xls"
```

And this is the same header information from Indy 10.5.8 (snapshot 10_4702 which I installed yesterday):

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="CDbEncbFvL7RZdOJ3DOIRoRBs=_nBsbZms"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2011 07:33:46 -0600

investigating more deeply, why does the boundary indicator change?

--h=_WzGWJei29fng7SqdPpDh1nkJxJZhiGc
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
    name="20111122.xls"
```

The time stamp is fixed, but now the boundary string is incorrect. The result is that there appears to be nothing at all in the message that gets added to my IMAP folder.

Here is the relevant code that creates the email message and attachment, sends it, and puts a copy into the IMAP folder:

```
  FTheMsg.Date := Now;  // FTheMsg is a component dropped onto the form
  FTheMsg.Recipients.EMailAddresses := edMailTo.Text;
  FTheMsg.ClearBody;
  FTheMsg.Subject := 'Glucose Readings ' + FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yy', FStartDate) + ' - ' +
              FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yy', FEndDate);
  FTheMsg.Body.Assign(FMemo.Lines);

  // create the attachment
  TIdAttachmentFile.Create(FTheMsg.MessageParts, fileName);

  // send the mail!
  FSmtp.Host := FSMTPHost;  // values set up elsewhere, FSmtp is a component on the form
  FImap.Host := FIMAPHost;  // FImap is also a component on the form

  FSmtp.Connect;
  try
    FSmtp.Send(FTheMsg);
    FImap.Connect;
    try
      if (not FImap.AppendMsg('Sent Items', FTheMsg, FTheMsg.LastGeneratedHeaders, [mfSeen]))     then
        StatusBar1.Panels[4].Text := 'Failed append msg';
    finally
      FImap.Disconnect;
    end;
  finally
    FSmtp.Disconnect;
  end;
```

As I said, the email that gets sent is fine and displays properly. But the one that is added to my IMAP folder (in FImap.AppendMsg() above) is incorrect. I've attempted to trace through the code to see where it might be going wrong, but frankly, I'm not familiar enough with Indy and the various email protocols/RFCs to be able to determine what's going wrong. About all I can tell is that the older version saves the message to a temporary file before appending it to the folder, while the newer version saves it to a memory stream instead. Obviously, something is different about that, but I'm currently too ignorant to determine what.

Is there a simple way to correct the timestamp problem in the old version? If so, that would be fine for my use, as everything else appears to be correct. If not, what else do I need to do to fix the problem exhibited here with the incorrect boundary string?

(As this is an application strictly for my own use, I can live with the incorrect date if I have to, but not with the "empty-appearing" copy in my 'Sent Items' folder.)

If more information is needed, I'll gladly supply whatever I can.

[Edit: I did incorporate something of a kludge in MY code, using the older version of Indy. I simply set the date/time of the message to UTC/GMT time before sending it, and that, at least, allows the message to contain the correct time at the receiver's end. I don't particularly care for that fix, but it does the trick.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the `TIdMessage.Body` property to hold your text when an attachment is present.  Put the text into a `TIdText` object instead.  Even better, use the `TIdMessageBuilder...` classes, such as `TIdMessageBuilderPlain`, to prepare the `TIdMessage` body for you.

Try this:

```
FTheMsg.Clear; 
FTheMsg.Date := Now;  // FTheMsg is a component dropped onto the form 
FTheMsg.Recipients.EMailAddresses := edMailTo.Text; 
FTheMsg.Subject := 'Glucose Readings ' + FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yy', FStartDate) + ' - ' + FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yy', FEndDate); 
FTheMsg.ContentType := 'multipart/mixed'; 

TIdText.Create(FTheMsg.MessageParts, FMemo.Lines).ContentType := 'text/plain';
TIdAttachmentFile.Create(FTheMsg.MessageParts, fileName); 

FSmtp.Connect; 
try 
  FSmtp.Send(FTheMsg); 
  FImap.Connect; 
  try 
    if (not FImap.AppendMsg('Sent Items', FTheMsg, nil, [mfSeen])) then 
      StatusBar1.Panels[4].Text := 'Failed append msg'; 
  finally 
    FImap.Disconnect; 
  end; 
finally 
  FSmtp.Disconnect; 
end;
```

Or:

```
FTheMsg.Clear; 
FTheMsg.Date := Now;  // FTheMsg is a component dropped onto the form 
FTheMsg.Recipients.EMailAddresses := edMailTo.Text; 
FTheMsg.Subject := 'Glucose Readings ' + FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yy', FStartDate) + ' - ' + FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yy', FEndDate); 

with TIdMessageBuilderPlain.Create do
try
  PlainText.Assign(FMemo.Lines);
  Attachments.Add(fileName); 
  FillMessage(FTheMsg);
finally
  Free;
end;

FSmtp.Connect; 
try 
  FSmtp.Send(FTheMsg); 
  FImap.Connect; 
  try 
    if (not FImap.AppendMsg('Sent Items', FTheMsg, nil, [mfSeen])) then 
      StatusBar1.Panels[4].Text := 'Failed append msg'; 
  finally 
    FImap.Disconnect; 
  end; 
finally 
  FSmtp.Disconnect; 
end;
```

Now, with that said, it is likely that it will still not work correctly either way.  `TIdIMAP4.AppendMsg()` calls `TIdMessage.SaveToStream()` internally, which regenerates the email content fresh (and thus alters the boundary used in the body).  Whether you pass in the pre-existing `TIdMessage.LastGeneratedHeaders` or let `TIdIMAP4.AppendMsg()` grab the current `TIdMessage.Headers`, they will be out of sync with the new boundary that `TIdMessage.SaveToStream()` generates.

To make sure both SMTP and IMAP4 are in sync, they need to receive the same data.  Try calling `TIdMessage.SaveToStream()` manually first with the `TIdMessage.NoEncode` property set to False, then set the `TIdMessage.NoDecode` property to True and call `TIdMessage.LoadFromStream()` to reload the saved data as-is into the `TIdMessage.Headers` and `TIdMessage.Body` properties, then call `TIdSMTP.Send()` and `TIdIMAP4.AppendMsg()` with the `TIdMessage.NoEncode` property set to True so the `TIdMessage.Headers` and `TIdMessage.Body` are sent as-is.

I know, this goes against what the `TIdIMAP4.AppendMsg()` comments/docs say to do.  `AppendMsg()` does not currently take MIME into account at all, so it does not ensure the MIME boundary in the header and body match each other.  I will try to check in a fix for that.  For Indy 11, Indy's entire MIME handling system is going to be redesigned, so I'll make sure it is possible to preserve boundaries, and/or to specify custom boundaries, so `AppendMsg()` can match the body boundary to the header boundary better.

IMAP4 is a very tricky protocol to work with in general.

Comment: Well, that had an affect, but not exactly what I was looking for. I created a memory stream, set FTheMsg.NoEncode := False, saved the message to the stream, reset FTheMsg.NoEncode := True and reloaded the message, then sent it with TIdSMTP.Send() and TIdIMAP4.AppendMsg(), passing NIL as the 'AdditionalHeaders' parameter. The result is that I got no attachment at all, and no text visible in the message!

Comment: This is the complete message after it was saved with NoEncode=False, then reloaded with NoEncode=True `code` Subject: Glucose Readings 11/07/11 - 11/20/11
To: philip.jurgenson@pejurgenson.net
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="D9uTCLury1wVu8hlPEcf=_0afpyB9eNLrK"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2011 15:00:10 -0600

This is a multi-part message in MIME format
.
With NoEncode=False, the saved message appears complete.

Comment: sorry, I misread the bit about setting NoEncode - I read it as NoDecode! Oops. If I do that correctly as in your note, the message arrives correctly, both at the recipient AND in my 'Sent Items' folder. Thank you VERY much for the help, it's much appreciated! I'll definitely accept this answer.

Comment: For future reference, I have started work on updating TIdIMAP4 to not need this `NoEncode`/`NoDecode` hack anymore, but I don't have an ETA on when it will be ready.

Comment: @RemyLebeau did you fix it? Do we still need NoEncode/Decode?

Comment: @Niki yes, it was fixed in mid-2014 in SVN rev 5124